# 'MS.Internal.Xaml.Parser.GenericTypeNameParser.TypeNameParserException' in System.Xaml.dll

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mahapps.metro

I am getting this exception now when I am attempting to run my project. I haven't changed any code.

> Exception thrown: 'MS.Internal.Xaml.Parser.GenericTypeNameParser.TypeNameParserException' in System.Xaml.dll
>
> Additional information: Prefix 'Custom' does not map to a namespace.

"Custom" refers to the MAHapps metro toolkit in App.xaml:

```
<Application xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:d1p1="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:Custom="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls" 
         xmlns:Custom1="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/shared"
```

I am not sure why this would change all of the sudden. I updated VS2015 to the latest version and it still won't work.

UPDATE:
I put the InitializeComponent() call inside a try catch in an attempt to get the exception object and now the exception is not being thrown.

```
        try
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.InnerException.Message);
        }
```

UPDATE 2:
It is still throwing the exception, but "catch (Exception ex)" ignores TypeNameParserException for some reason.

Comment: While in this example it probably wouldn't matter... before you get downvoted into oblivion on a future question, don't post pictures of exceptions or code.  Get the full exception details from the exception object itself and paste that into your question.  Post it and the relevant code into your question.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it for now. I will get the additional data

Comment: FYI, I checked the latest version of the mahapps assembly and the xmlns namespace is correct.  There might be an inner exception with the real cause. Something weird is going on.  Have you tried cleaning/rebuilding/removing and reinstalling nuget packages?

Comment: I tried re-installing mahMetro after I got the message, but it's still throwing the same exception.

Comment: I thought I should mention: I just went back and tried running an older version of the project (Which definitely never had this issue) and it's throwing the same exception.

Comment: Normally, these are the standard namespace conventions: `xmlns:Controls="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/controls"` and `xmlns:Custom="http://metro.mahapps.com/winfx/xaml/shared" `

Comment: @user3232337 I would suggest what jstreet says. but the name doesn't matter. It sounds more that your vs installation is corrupt. You should try clean all bin/obj folders of your project, clean designer cache of vs and restart your system...

Answer (score 0):

Full uninstall and reinstall of VS 2015 fixed the problem.

Comment: Was the problem with all projects or only with one project? I only have this on one project. Is it worth installing vs new?

Comment: I don't remember how many projects were affected, but I never ran into this problem again after reinstalling VS...

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the exception is caught somewhere in the XAML processing of WPF. So that’s why you can’t catch the exception. The problem you were having came from the setting of Visual Studio. Here you can tell what to do when an exception occurs. (Since VS 2015 There’s a special window for controlling that. Debug -> Windows -> exception settings) If there’s a mark in that CLR exception, Visual Studio will stop and show you the exception even it will not show up in regular operation. You can try to get the problem back by marking all exceptions to show up.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue in a WPF.NET solution in VS 2022.  I had recently turned off "Enable just my code" to debug in the `Release` configuration.  When I switched back to `Debug` configuration I noticed these errors.

I had to turn "Enable just my code" back on to stop recieving this error.

[image]